# I want to test something but WordPress is preventing it. How do I turn off automatic HTTPS forwarding

Tags: wordpress

I did a lot of research to wp-config.php

define ('WP_SITEURL', 'http://test.example.com');
define ('WP_HOME', 'http://test.example.com');

I made additions such as , but I did not succeed, I installed 5.0, how do I turn off automatic forwarding or is there a version that is not available? I made additions to .htaccess.

Comment: Why do you think that https forwarding is the problem? What are you trying to test that breaks if there is https forwarding going on?

Comment: Like @tucuxi mentioned, we need more context. HTTPS redirection could also be set-up on the server by the way.

Comment: you must check htaccess should be like 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

And define below in wp-config.php

define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);

Comment: Yea is from server